# How to force using particular MediaType in RestEasy client

Tags: json, resteasy

I have a shared API and services are annotated

```
@Produces({"application/json","application/x-jackson-smile"})
@Consumes({"application/json","application/x-jackson-smile"})
public class AServiceClass {
```

So default is JSON - this will be preferred when using browser AJAX calls.

However I have a RestEasy client which I create using

```
ProxyFactory.create(AServiceClass.class, url)
```

And I want this client to use SMILE for both inbound and aoutbound communication. Of course it picks first item from @Consumes and tries marshalling to JSON.

I'm using RestEasy 2.3.5

How to force the client to use SMILE marshalling?

How to force the client to accept SMILE instead of JSON?

Answer (score 1):

Actually it turns out that you ( I mean I :-) ) **can't do this**.

Checking [MediaTypeHelper.getConsumes()](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-jaxrs/2.3.5.Final/org/jboss/resteasy/util/MediaTypeHelper.java#MediaTypeHelper.getConsumes%28java.lang.Class%2Cjava.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject%29) shows that always **first** annotation value is picked to determine marshalling media type.

```
return MediaType.valueOf(consume.value()[0]);
```

The same happens when it comes to figuring out accept header. The code uses [MediaTypeHelper.getProduces()](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-jaxrs/2.3.5.Final/org/jboss/resteasy/util/MediaTypeHelper.java#MediaTypeHelper.getProduces%28java.lang.Class%2Cjava.lang.reflect.Method%29)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by specifying the value for the header Accept

```
             Response response = client.target(host + "/yourpath").request()
                 .header(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, "application/x-jackson-smile")
                 .get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this with a `ClientRequestFilter`, which is more usful if you are using proxies of your JAX-RS annotated classes. For example

```
public class AcceptedHeaderFilter implements ClientRequestFilter
{
    private final MediaType acceptedType;

    public AcceptedHeaderFilter(final MediaType acceptedType)
    {
        super();
        this.acceptedType = acceptedType;
    }

    @Override
    public void filter(final ClientRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException
    {
        requestContext.getHeaders().get(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT).clear();
        requestContext.getHeaders().get(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT).add(acceptedType.toString());
    }

}
```

If you are using Resteasy, you can register on your `ResteasyWebTarget`

```
MediaType contentType = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE;
final ResteasyWebTarget target = buildTarget();
target.getResteasyClient().register(new AcceptedHeaderFilter(contentType));
```

CXF or Jersey will let you register the filter, but will require you to do it in a slightly different way.